# Push topic and empApi filtered subscription not working after record page refresh (F5)

Tags: streaming-api, pushtopic

I need to use filtered subscription using lightning:empAPI for Push Topic notifications. But it does not work with Id filter after records page refresh (F5) whereas when it subscribes on the first place the notifications are coming in.
Does it mean that only one active filtered subscription has to exist for the record and user session? If so how can I unsubscribe prior the component is reloaded and new subscription is initiated during refresh (F5).

```
<aura:attribute name="channel" type="String" default="{!'/topic/QuoteProcessing?Id=' + v.recordId}"/>
<!--<aura:attribute name="channel" type="String" default="/topic/QuoteProcessing"/>-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" closable="false"/>

// doInit just executes helper.subscribe
helper.subscribe(component, event);

// helper.subscribe
subscribe : function(component, event) {
        const empApi = component.find('empApi');
        const channel = component.get('v.channel');
        const replayId = -1;
        //var Qchannel = '/topic/QuoteProcessing?Id='+component.get('v.recordId');
        // Subscribe to an event
        //console.log('Qchannel '+Qchannel);
        empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, $A.getCallback(eventReceived => {
            console.log('Received event ', JSON.stringify(eventReceived));  
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();  
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
            mode : "dismissable",
                message : "Processing  - "+eventReceived.data.sobject.ProcessingStatus__c,
                type : "info",
                duration : 8000
            });
            toastEvent.fire();   
        }))
        .then(subscription => {
            console.log('Subscribed to channel ', subscription.channel);
            console.log('subscription ', JSON.stringify(subscription));
            component.set('v.subscription', subscription);
        });    
        empApi.onError($A.getCallback(error => {
            console.log('EMP API error from subscribe: '+ JSON.stringify(error));
        }));   
    }
```

PushTopic query contains Id and the field I am changing in SELECT clause.
Subscription is established but notifications are not coming.

Comment: Push Topic query: SELECT Id, Name, ProcessingStatus__c FROM MyCustomObject

Comment: Andrew - this seems to be a known issue with Salesforce, refer to the question linked as duplicate for details.

Comment: Jayant - I have seen that question but I cannot comment on it with my score) So, it seems that it was posted fairly long time ago. Is there a resolution in place, was the fix deployed by Salesforce? The link to EMP connector on git does not give me any idea how to bypass the problem...

Comment: Let me check on that. I will comment on that question to see if it has been resolved.

Comment: Andrew - While I have commented on the answer there, I have also [tweeted](https://twitter.com/jayantkdas/status/1108394468699451395) to see if I get a response, will keep this thread posted.

Comment: @JayantDas, I have added new details to the description that make this issue distinct.

Comment: If you are saying that filtered subscriptions worked at first place but you are having another issue, then that will categorize as a different question. Your original question seemed to have an issue with filtered subscription itself and thus was marked as duplicate. But if not, then you should open a new one.

Comment: @JayantDas I have an option here "If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question." And I've chosen to edit because the another question was never denoted as resolved.

Comment: Your question is a bit different that asked earlier. The reason it was marked as duplicate was because earlier you seemed to have same issue, but after this edit it seems you are able to subscribe but it does not seem to work on a refresh, is that correct? If my understanding is right, then you should definitely open a new question. Because this is already closed, it may get lost and you may not be able to get a solution if one exists. Edits usually preserve the ask of original question. If you feel this a correct edit, we can vote to get this reopened.